# Are there any Female manifestations of Shiva and Vishnu (other than Mohini)?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, puranas, tantra, goddess

Has Lord Shiva Ever taken any Female manifestations in the Puranas or Shaiva Agamas/Tantras? Similarly, Does Lord Vishnu have any feminine manifestations? (Other than Mohini because I know that one) in Puranas or Vaishnava Agamas?

Btw. I am not seeking any references where their Shaktis or consorts are spoken of as their forms or such. I wish to see verses, where the Male deities themselves directly take to  a female manifestation like how Lord Vishnu took the form of Mohini.

Also If any such manifestations exist, what are they called? Please answer with scriptural refernces.

Comment: Maheshwari matrika for Shiva, Vaishnavai matrika for Vishnu.